# zero set of polynomial over the field of rational functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, rational-functions

Based on [1, Section 9.5], it is known that for any multivariate polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$ with indeterminate $x$ and $y$ (take two variables for simplicity), denoted by $f(x,y)$, it holds that $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \mathcal{X}$ is open and dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (if $ \mathcal{X} \not= \mathbb{R}^2$), where
$$
\mathcal{X} = \{[x,y]\in \mathbb{R}^2 | f(x,y) = 0\}.
$$

The question is as follows.

Denote the field of rational functions as $\mathcal{V}$, and consider now a multivariate polynomial over the field of rational functions, i.e. $\mathcal{V}[x,y]$. Denote such polynomial as $g(x,y)$. Let 
$$
\bar{\mathcal{X}} = \{[x,y] \in \mathcal{V}^2 | g(x,y) = 0\}.
$$

Does it holds true that $\mathcal{V}^2 \setminus \bar{\mathcal{X}}$ is open and dense in $\mathcal{V}^2$ when $\bar{\mathcal{X}} \not= \mathcal{V}^2$?

[1]  J. W. Polderman and J. C. Willems, "Introduction to mathematical systems theory: a behavioral approach", Springer Science, 1997.

Comment: I believe this depends on what kind of metric you’re using on the space $\mathcal{V}$.

Comment: That is true. I will specify the metric I am using

Comment: For any field $k$ any (non-zero) polynomial of $k[x]$ has finitely many zeros in $k$.

Comment: @renus: Thanks for your answer. It seems that univariate case is trivial. I have edited the question for the multivariate case.